# React Native - How to pass array props and receive different uri

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-props

I would like to pass `array props` in `LiveSellersBottomBox` so that I can pass its props to `SellerLiveBox`. The code I created displays the same images as it receives the same image data. What I want is to receive different `uri` from `LiveSellersBottomBox` data. Could you let me know how I should do?

SellerLiveBox Code Below :

```js
const sellerLiveBox = [
  {
    image:
      'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/kendall-jenner-is-seen-in-soho-on-september-8-2018-in-new-news-photo-1591628353.jpg',
  },
  {
    image:
      'https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018212/rs_1024x759-180312100120-1024-Gigi-Hadid-Jeans-Sale.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto&output-quality=90',
  },
  {
    image:
      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSe-Hcz3sk22LZqIyriB7XYLQWyg-kxP907pA&usqp=CAU',
  },
  {
    image:
      'https://media.glamour.com/photos/5d8e08e143725900082c4bfc/6:7/w_3067,h_3579,c_limit/GettyImages-1033321018.jpg',
  },
  {
    image:
      'https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018212/rs_1024x759-180312100120-1024-Gigi-Hadid-Jeans-Sale.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto&output-quality=90',
  },
];

const SellerLiveBox = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {sellerLiveBox.map((image, index) => (
        <View
          style={[
            styles.container,
            { flexDirection: index % 2 === 0 ? 'row-reverse' : 'row' },
          ]}
        >
          // This is the part I would like to fix
          <LiveSellerBottomBox source={{ uri: image.image }} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

SellerLiveBox.propTypes = {
  imgs: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
};

export default SellerLiveBox;
```

LiveSellersBottomBox Code Below :

```js
const LiveSellersBottomBox = ({ source }) => { // I should change this part
  return (
    <>
      <View style={[styles.smallBox, styles.box]}>
        <Image
          style={[styles.smallImage, { marginBottom: 5 }]}
          source={source} // here as well
        />
        <Image
          style={[styles.smallImage]}
          source={source} // here as well
        />
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.largeBox, styles.box, { marginRight: 5 }]}>
        <Image
          style={[styles.largeImage]}
          source={source} // here as well
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

LiveSellersBottomBox.propTypes = {
  source: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
};

export default LiveSellersBottomBox;
```

Comment: you are using same image in LiveSellersBottomBox component so image rendered will be same too

Comment: @KetanRamteke Yes, I do know that logic, and my problem is I have no idea how to access the right way.. That is why I am asking.

Comment: here is what you can do, store the array of different images in each object and then pass them to LiveSellerBottomBox and use them, wait I will send you the demo app

Comment: here is how you can achieve that: https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/moody-almond

Comment: @KetanRamteke Now it does display what I expected. Thank you so much. What I needed to do was making even the image data, `sellerLiveBox`, as arrays, so that the props, `source`, can receive the images! I comprehended it thanks to you.

Comment: glad it helped, you are welcome. Will you accept the answer if a post that same solution :D

Comment: @KetanRamteke Absolutely I will, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229187/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-uheny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the images in an array of an object having three images each and then render it:

Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/moody-almond)

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const sellerLiveBox = [
  {
    images: [
      'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/kendall-jenner-is-seen-in-soho-on-september-8-2018-in-new-news-photo-1591628353.jpg',
      'https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018212/rs_1024x759-180312100120-1024-Gigi-Hadid-Jeans-Sale.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto&output-quality=90',
      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSe-Hcz3sk22LZqIyriB7XYLQWyg-kxP907pA&usqp=CAU',
    ],
  },
  {
    images: [
      'https://media.glamour.com/photos/5d8e08e143725900082c4bfc/6:7/w_3067,h_3579,c_limit/GettyImages-1033321018.jpg',

      'https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018212/rs_1024x759-180312100120-1024-Gigi-Hadid-Jeans-Sale.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto&output-quality=90',
      'https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018212/rs_1024x759-180312100120-1024-Gigi-Hadid-Jeans-Sale.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto&output-quality=90',
    ],
  },
];

const SellerLiveBox = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {sellerLiveBox.map((image, index) => (
        <View
          style={[
            styles.container,
            { flexDirection: index % 2 === 0 ? 'row-reverse' : 'row' },
          ]}>
          <LiveSellerBottomBox source={image.images} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const LiveSellerBottomBox = ({ source }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 10,
      }}>
      <View style={[styles.smallBox, styles.box]}>
        <Image
          style={[styles.smallImage, { marginBottom: 5 }]}
          source={{ uri: source[0] }}
        />
        <Image style={[styles.smallImage]} source={{ uri: source[1] }} />
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.largeBox, styles.box, { marginRight: 5 }]}>
        <Image style={[styles.largeImage]} source={{ uri: source[2] }} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SellerLiveBox;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },

  smallImage: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  smallBox: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  largeBox: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  largeImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
});
```